# Welches deutsche Wort entspricht am besten dem Englischen „disingenuous“?

Tags: english-to-german

Man hört oft „he is disingenuous“ in englischsprachigen Ländern, oder „he is being disingenuous.“

Als eine mögliche Übersetzung, hab ich „heuchlerisch“ gelesen, aber das kommt mir falsch vor. Ist die Übersetzung „unaufrichtig“ oder gibt es ein passenderes Wort?

Comment: Bitte, keine Antworten in englischer Sprache

Comment: *unaufrichtig* kann die richtige Wahl sein, abhängig vom Kontext. Worum genau geht es denn?

Comment: Man hört oft „he is disingenuous“ in englischsprachigen Ländern, oder „he is being disingenuous.“

Comment: Als eine mögliche Übersetzung, hab ich „heuchlerisch“ gelesen, aber das stimmt nicht, oder?

Comment: Heuchelnd or heuchlerisch wird üblicherweise mit *hypocritical* übersetzt.

Comment: @Jan: "heuchlerisch" *könnte* in einigen Situation passen. "Disingenious" bedeutet ja, dass man irreführt, und oft dadurch, dass man sich dümmer stellt als man ist. Man heuchelt also ein wenig Ignoranz oder Dummheit vor. "Hypocritical" ist eher "scheinheilig", i.e. man bezichtigt andere von etwas, das man selber (auch) gemacht hat.

Comment: @Jan, da Kommentare nicht für die Ewigkeit sind und deine übersprüngliche Frage schon wegen ihrer Kürze kritisiert wurde, habe ich deinen Kommentare in deine Frage eingebaut.

Comment: Für eine saubere Antwort bräuchte man den genauen Kontext. Asking just so is a bit disingenuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mit solchen Fragen kann es oft hilfreich sein, danach zu suchen, was andere als Übersetzung benutzt haben. Dafür sind zweisprachige Korpora, z.B. [linguee.de](https://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/disingenuous.html), perfekt geeignet.

Da habe ich folgende Übersetzungsmöglichkeiten gefunden:

> unaufrichtig
>   irreführend
>   hinterlistig
>   verlogen
>   doppelzüngig (in der Form „Doppelzüngigkeit“ als Übersetzung für “disingenuous language”
>   unredlich

Da es in sprachlichen Fragen oft vorkommt, dass sich keine Übersetzung mit der originalen Bedeutung hundertprozentig überschneidet, muss man die Absicht des Originalsatzes einfach so gut wie möglich in der Zielsprache wiedergeben.

Für den Satz “He is being disingenuous” schlag ich vor, das Wort „unaufrichtig“ zu benutzen.

Comment: Alles schön und gut, aber eigentlich kommt es auf den Kontext an. Ohne einen solchen würde ich keine Antwort wagen.